# Checking if string ends with a number throws "unexpected operator"

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm trying to check wether the file name of the script I run ends with a number or not:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
name=$(basename "$0" .sh)
[ $name =~ ^.[0-9]$ ] && numb=$(echo $name | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g') || numb=1
echo $numb
```

my shell file is named `mh03.sh` and this is the output if I run it:

```
$ ./mh3.sh
./mh3.sh: 3: [: mh3: unexpected operator
1
```

can someone tell me why I get this exception and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The regex match operator `=~` is not supported in the single square brackets. You need double square brackets for it to work.

```
[[ $name =~ ^.[0-9]$ ]]
```

Note that you don't need a regex, you can use a normal pattern:

```
[[ $name = *[0-9] ]]
```

or, if you need the name to contain something before the digit,

```
[[ $name = *?[0-9] ]]
```

Comment: Oh good to know!
But now it gives me the following exception: `./mh3.sh: 3: ./mh3.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: I found the second issue by myself... Appearently I have to use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`... I just wonder why.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is _not_ the same as "bash".  If you want to use bash semantics then use `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

[: =~: binary operator expected

the error is `[$name =~ ^.[0-9]$ ]`
encolse it with [],

try,

```
#!/bin/sh
name=$(basename "$0" .sh)
[[ $name =~ ^.[0-9]$ ]] && numb=$(echo $name | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g') || numb=1
echo $num
```

and it works.

Comment: I don't know which one of you were first. But either way it just prints me a new exception:
`./mh3.sh: 3: ./mh3.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: I found the second issue by myself... Appearently I have to use #!/bin/bash instead of #!/bin/sh... I just wonder why.

Comment: i guess you /bin/bash is not really bash, try typing this and execute,  /bin/bash -c "type [["